# MVVM + Databinding

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

Let's suppose I have a weather app, in which I am getting data from a data provider and saving it my local database. Now I have a `Repository` class whose job is to fetch data either from API or local DB depending on certain conditions. I have a Settings page, user has opted to show temperature in °F and distance in km. The data I got from API is °C for temperature and mi for distance. My `View` requested to `ViewModel` to fetch data from `Repository`. The `Repository` fetched the data and returned a model named `WeatherData`. Now the data I have is in °C and mi. Is it a good idea that using `DataBinding` I import a `Util` class in my layout file, containing the helping methods to converts these units in accordance with user chose in Settings? Or should there be methods in `WeatherData` that will convert the data and shown in the view using databinding? Or is there a another to do this in the correct way?

Comment: To the person who down voted it: thank you for the down vote. Because of it I came to know my question is not "worthy" but it would have helped me more if you would have stated the reason of down vote in the comment. You may have down voted because: 1. My understanding is poor. 2: The question is not clear 3: It's a stupid question. 4: Or some other reason. It will remain a mystery and I will never be able improve my future questions. :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question and can have different possible answers but I will throw my opinion on the matter.

One way to look at ViewModels is to think of it as the 'model' of the view. In this way, you can be sure that your view would be very lean and dummy, which is ideal since they can be difficult, if not impossible, to test. And since VMs are also the layer between the view and the model, it is a perfect place to do data and type conversions. Benefits include testability (as I said, it is difficult to validate conversion logic in XML) and better maintainability (if for some reason you have to change your view in the future).

Another point to consider is clean architecture. In clean architecture, dependencies are inwards. The upper layer models should map to and from the model of the lower layer. In your case, the `Repository` already served its purpose of providing the `WeatherData`, it should not care about how the data is going to be used on the upper layer.

So to answer your question, I think it should be in the `ViewModel` or if you want to decouple further in cases of multiple conversions in different views, a `Converter` layer in between your domain layer and ViewModel.

Comment: I like the idea of decoupling conversion part. As I am not really into unit testing yet. I have just started exploring it, I have a question, can't I test the output of those helping methods in `Utils` class even if used them in XML? I can mock the input data and pass it on while unit testing those methods.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes you can test your Utils independently. But you cannot verify if these functions are used correctly in your view since you cannot test them.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I will wait for a day more, if I didn't get any better answer, I will mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is based on your setting you have to show °C/°F and mi/km.

You can have the conversion logic inside your model class `WeatherData`

Like,

```
class WeatherData{

    private float degrees;

    public float getCelsius(){
        //conversion
    }

    public float getFahrenheit(){
        //conversion
    }

    private float km;

    public float getKm(){
        //conversion
    }

    public float getMiles(){
        //conversion
    }

}
```

And in your viewmodel you can have flags like `boolean celsius,km;`

In the layout you can define these three variables.

```
    <data>
        <variable
            name="celsius"
            type="Boolean"/>
        <variable
            name="km"
            type="Boolean"/>
        <variable
            name="data"
            type="WeatherData"/>
    </data>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{km?data.km:data.miles}" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_temperature"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{celsius?data.celsius:data.fahrenheit}"
        />
```